# Attach only one file from a location where there are multiple files

Tags: vba, outlook

Every month I send about two, three hundred individual emails with a single Excel file as an attachment.

Is it possible to import only one Excel file from a particular location (in that location there will be more than one Excel file) then after sending the email Outlook opens a new email and attaches the next Excel file.

Below is the VBA code written so far, but Outlook imports all the files from that location.

```
Sub Outlook_Project()

Dim origEmail As Object
Dim newEmail As MailItem
Dim MyPath As String

Set origEmail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\new folder\Template.oft")
newEmail.Subject = "mySubject"

newEmail.Recipients.Add "test@test"
StrPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\"

With newEmail
    strFile = Dir(StrPath & "*.*")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        .Attachments.Add StrPath & strFile
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
End With

newEmail.Display
Set origEmail = Nothing
Set newEmail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know the name of the file you want to send? If so you could take out the `do while` loop, which loops through the whole folder and adds every file as an attachment, and fill `strFile` with the filename you want to send.

Comment: The name of the file may vary from month to month.

Comment: And do you know the name of the file you want to send each month? Something like `testfile-jan.xlsx` for January? Or do you know part of the name which is unique in the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you create a new mail and attach every file in that directory to that mail. If you'd like to generate a mail for each file, you should iterate over the files and then create the mail inside the loop. You should also think about the mapping between file and recipient, if there is more than one.

Comment: I'm afraid he needs to send a single file to more recipients. So, no need to generate a mail for each file. He needs a recipients list and iterate between them in order to attach the same file for each recipient...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub testOutlook()
 Dim origEmail As Object, newEmail As Object
 Dim StrPath As String, strFile As String, mailsList() As String
 Dim myFileName As String, El As Variant

 StrPath = "C:\Users\your_user\Desktop\Test\"
 mailsList = Split("test1@test.com,test2@test.com,test3@test.com", ",")
             'You can also collect the mail accounts name from a sheet list (on row or column).
 myFileName = "Test1.txt" ' You must find a way to create it according to some criteria

 Set origEmail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

 For Each El In mailsList
    Set newEmail = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\new folder\Template.oft")
    newEmail.Subject = "mySubject"
    newEmail.Recipients.Add El
    newEmail.Attachments.Add StrPath & myFileName
    newEmail.send
 Next

 Set origEmail = Nothing: Set newEmail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Take care to change the appropriate paths (of your computer) for `strPath` and template path. Do the same, of course, with the dummy mail account names (separated by comma)...

Answer (score 0):

Based on RicingFX's idea I tried a different approach, below you can find the working code, it is all I need:

```
Sub Outlook_Project()

Dim StrFile As String, StrPath As String
Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application
Dim MailOutLook As Outlook.MailItem


Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

StrPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\"
StrFile = Dir("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\*.xlsx")


Do While Len(StrFile) > 0


Set MailOutLook = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Template.oft")

With MailOutLook
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Test@Test.com"
.Subject = "MySubject"



.Attachments.Add StrPath + StrFile
.Display


End With
StrFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Thank you guys for your support.